# How to save the response From My server , and How can i access That data

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, iphone

Hi  i am getting the response from my server successfully.i need to access the user_id send by the server in my app.

check my code:

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];



        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my url"];
        NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];




        NSString * params=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"mobile=%@",[self.reqnum text ]];

        NSLog(@"%@",params);
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                           completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                               NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                               if(error == nil)
                                                               {
                                                                   NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                                                     NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);



                                                                   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"Y" forKey:@"login"];

                                                                   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


                                                               }


                                                           }];
        [dataTask resume];
```

for this code i am getting the response like:

here i need to access the user_id in my app .so can i get that particular user_id.

Thank You.

Comment: Create a model class for user object. Convert response in dictionary form as it is JSON, not string. Create initializer method for class with dictionary. Access desired attributes of desired object like you do with normal class instances. As there will be only one user, make it a singleton class. Then user attributes will be available everywhere in your app. That will be proper approach. For quick solution, use ShahiM's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since original solutions have already been posted, I will focus on longer & more tedious way which I think is the proper way to handle the elephant in the room. This will help you in the longer run.

**Create a Singleton class since there can be only one user logged in at one time.**

`SharedUser.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SharedUser : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* userId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* userName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* subscriptionStatus;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* registerDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* expiryDate;
+(SharedUser*) getInstance;

@end
```

`SharedUser.m`

```
#import "SharedUser.h"

@implementation SharedUser



static SharedUser * sharedInstance;



+(SharedUser*) getInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(sharedInstance == nil)
        {

            sharedInstance = [[SharedUser alloc] init];
            sharedInstance.userName = @"";
            sharedInstance.userId = @"";
            sharedInstance.subscriptionStatus = @"";
            sharedInstance.registerDate = @"";
            sharedInstance.expiryDate = @"";
            return sharedInstance;
        }
        else
        {
            return  sharedInstance;
        }

    }
}
```

**Convert your response into `NSDictionary`.**

```
NSDictionary *json_dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];;//From Santosh Reddy's Answer
```

**Populate your sharedInstance with the result attributes:**

```
[SharedUser getInstance].userId = [json_dict objectForKey:@"user_id"];
[SharedUser getInstance].userName = [json_dict objectForKey:@"username"];
[SharedUser getInstance].subscriptionStatus = [json_dict objectForKey:@"subscription_status"];
[SharedUser getInstance].registryDate = [json_dict objectForKey:@"register_date"];//Better to use NSDate type instead of NSString
[SharedUser getInstance].expiryDate = [json_dict objectForKey:@"expiry_date"];
```

Now your user's attributes will be available anywhere in the App. You just need to import `SharedUser.h` to desired `UIView`, `UIViewController` & type following to access your data:

```
NSString *userId = [SharedUser getInstance].userId;
```

Also Note that I am using singleton pattern because I am assuming that you only need to handle one user's attributes which will be used in multiple viewcontrollers over the span of time. If you need multiple users saved, create a similar user model class and populate them in a similar way. (Just don't make them singleton).

Also I would suggest that you should read Ray Wenderlich's series tutorials on:

[1. Object Oriented Design](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81952/intro-object-oriented-design-swift-part-1) 
[2. Design Patterns](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns) 
[3. Intro to iOS design patterns](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @NSNoob

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the value in other classes then :

First create a data Model Class, parse the data dictionary/JSON and store it.
Using the completion block you can return the specific/received user_id to the caller.

Here you are getting in JSON, you can parse it and get the desired data:

```
NSDictionary *respDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSString *userID = respDict[@"user_id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The response is a JSON object. If what you are asking is how to parse it, then there is an inbuilt JSON parser in iOS.

```
NSDictionary *json_dict = [text JSONValue];
NSString *userID = [result objectForKey:@"user_id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a NSDictionary to get json data.

```
   NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
     if(error == nil)
             {
      NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
      NSString *userID = [dictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"];
}

 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its upto you how to store data and if you want to parse it, then try

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [responseString JSONValue];
NSString *user_id = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"user_id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the data that you're getting in block as below.

```
completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
     if(error == nil)
             {
     NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    NSDictionary *response = JSON[@"user_id"];
}

 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a NSDictionary, save JSON data in it and fetch **user_id** from it. Like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryName=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSString *user_id= [dictionaryName valueForKey:@"user_id"];
```

Comment: You're welcome. Kindly, up vote if you find answers helpful.